# NodeJS, can I spawn a command such as "lerna" with several interactions?

Tags: node.js, npm, workspace, spawn, lerna

I am trying to simplify my workflow and for that I'd need to run from `Node`
 a script that execute some commands

The ones that are no interactive, such as `git add *` and so on I can do with `require('child_process').exec` just fine

But the ones that require the user intervention such as `lerna blah` I cannot

I've tried something like

```js
  let { stdout, stderr } = await spawn('lerna', [lerna_option, '--no-push'], {
    env: process.env,
    stdio: 'inherit',
    shell: true,
  })

  if (stdout) console.log('\n' + stdout)
  if (stderr) console.log('\n' + stderr)
```

But it gives me one interaction and then goes on, not allowing me to ask all the questions and run as intended

Is there any **simple** way to accomplish this?